# Short story about government-mandated equality

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

I am trying to recall a short story I read perhaps 10 years ago. It was a story about a dystopian future where people were not allowed to have any advantage and were artificially handicapped.

What I remember so far:

- Intelligent people had an implant that distracted them with a loud noise.
- People who were too fast were weighed down.
- Beautiful people were forced to wear ugly masks.

Comment: Harrison Bergeron

Comment: @MarkOlson Thank you, that was it!